Guix: How to add an environment variable in a guix.scm file for use with guix shell? Or is it not possible?
guix shell allows users to create a shell and control what resources are available.
How can I use the guix.scm file to specify an environment variable in this shell environment?
In this specific example, I'm just looking for a TEST environment variable with the value 2.
ChatGPT gave me two suggestions below which did not work, nor are these options defined in the package reference. Both give me the same error: extraneous field initializers.
I also saw this thread about the inability to define environment variables in a manifest file and one user said that it should be possible to do with guix.scm files (or, the type of files passed to guix shell with --file argument), but I'm not sure if that's correct. I tried the guile setenv Scheme procedure but I get the error: invalid field specifier.
Here's an example guix.scm with the three options I tried at the bottom:
(use-modules
    (guix)
    (guix build-system gnu)
    ((guix licenses) #:prefix license:)
    (gnu packages bison)
    (gnu packages compression)
    (gnu packages flex)
    (gnu packages m4)
    (gnu packages tls)
)

(package
    (name "coreboot")
    (version "dan")
    (source (local-file "." #:recursive? #t))
    (build-system gnu-build-system)
    (native-inputs
        (list
            bison
            flex
            m4
            openssl
            zlib
        )
    )
    (synopsis "coreboot")
    (description "coreboot")
    (home-page "https://www.coreboot.org/")
    (license license:expat)
    (shell '(#:variables (,"TEST=2"))) ; Does not work
    (environment-variables '("TEST" "2")) ; Does not work
    (setenv "TEST" "2") ; Does not work
)


Using setenv at the top level of the file does work:
(use-modules
    (guix)
    (guix build-system gnu)
    ((guix licenses) #:prefix license:)
    (gnu packages bison)
    (gnu packages compression)
    (gnu packages flex)
    (gnu packages m4)
    (gnu packages tls)
)

(setenv "TEST" "2") ; Works!

(package
    (name "coreboot")
    (version "dan")
    (source (local-file "." #:recursive? #t))
    (build-system gnu-build-system)
    (native-inputs
        (list
            bison
            flex
            m4
            openssl
            zlib
        )
    )
    (synopsis "coreboot")
    (description "coreboot")
    (home-page "https://www.coreboot.org/")
    (license license:expat)
)

$ echo $TEST

$ guix shell
guix shell: loading environment from '.../guix.scm'
[env]$ echo $TEST
2

